# PHP Slim não consegue fazer o bind

Tags: php, slim

Eu fiz uma função para inserir em lista de um JSON, só que quando vai preparar o PDO, substituir os valores acontece um erro, não estou vendo onde estou errando.

```
public function newDeviceList(){
        global $app;
        $dados = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
        $dados = (sizeof($dados)==0)? $_POST : $dados;
        $keys = array_keys($dados); //Paga as chaves do array
        /*
        O uso de prepare e bindValue é importante para se evitar SQL Injection
        */

        $keys = array_keys($dados);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++) {

            $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO MyTable (".implode(',', $keys).") 
            VALUES (:".implode(",:", $keys).")");

            foreach($dados[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
                $sth ->bindValue(':'.$key,$value);

            }
            $sth->execute();
        }




        //Retorna o id inserido
        $app->render('default.php',["data"=>['MyId'=>$this->PDO->lastInsertId()]],200); 
    }
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
<strong>Message:</strong> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

---

Senão colocar o for para percorrer o array eu consigo inserir normalmente.. quando é apenas um valor sem ser lista.. não é variavel global não.

Comment: a palavra-chave public é usada apenas em declarações de função/variável de dentro de uma classe. Como você não está usando uma classe, você precisa removê-la do seu código.

Comment: E é má prática declarar como global uma variável de uma função. não é necessário.

Comment: confere seu foreach pois o erro acontece quando existem parâmetros a mais ou a menos em relação ao bindValue. Ou você pode desutilizar o FOR e FOREACH e fazer apenas o FOREACH com seu INSERT e não usar seu array_keys lá de cima, realizar tudo dentro do laço mesmo.

Comment: Eliseu... obrigado.. vou tentar isso... acredito que vai dar certo..

Comment: Blza fera, tamos ae.